# Как вызвать атрибуты функции и списка и изменить её значение?

Tags: python

Есть примерно такой код

```
class Rheology:

    def __init__(self):
        self.rpm_600 = 0
        self.rpm_300 = 0
        self.rpm_200 = 0
        self.rpm_100 = 0
        self.rh.rpm_6 = 0
        self.rh.rpm_3 = 0

    def visc(self):
        pv = self.rpm_600 - self.rpm_300
        return pv

    def func_1():
        return self.rh.rpm_6 * self.rh.rpm_3

    def func_2():
        pass


rh = Rheology()

func_list = [rh.rpm_600, rh.rpm_300]

for i in func_list:
    # не знаю как правильно написать...
    i = int(input('Введите значение'))

print('Решение 1: ', rh.visc())
print('Решение 2: ', rh.func_1())
```

Можно таким образом или иным, перебирая список переменных из списка, присваивать им значение?
Т.е. хочу избавится от огромной кучи кода типа:

```
rh = Rheology()
rh.rpm_600 = int(input('Введите значение'))
rh.rpm_300 = int(input('Введите значение'))
rh.rpm_200 = int(input('Введите значение'))
rh.rpm_100 = int(input('Введите значение'))
rh.rpm_6 = int(input('Введите значение'))
rh.rpm_3 = int(input('Введите значение'))
```

Comment: Через костыли можно. Но нужно ли? IMHO, хранить большое количество каких-то данных в переменных не лучшая идея. Может, Вам стоит использовать словарь (`dict`)?

Comment: Наверно лучше, но не так красиво выглядит код... Поиграюсь со словарём)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Rheology:
#    def __init__(self):
#        self.rpm_600 = 0
#        self.rpm_300 = 0

    def visc(self, rpm_600, rpm_300):
        self.rpm_600 = rpm_600
        self.rpm_300 = rpm_300
        pv = self.rpm_600 - self.rpm_300
        return pv


rh = Rheology()

_list = []
for i in range(2):
    _list.append(int(input(f'Введите значение {i+1}: ')))

print(rh.visc(*_list))
```

---

**Update**

Попробуйте так:

```
class Rheology:
    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        self.rpm_600 = kwargs['rpm_600']
        self.rpm_300 = kwargs['rpm_300']
        self.rpm_200 = kwargs['rpm_200']
        self.rpm_100 = kwargs['rpm_100']
        self.rpm_6 = kwargs['rpm_6']
        self.rpm_3 = kwargs['rpm_3']

    def visc(self):
        pv = self.rpm_600 - self.rpm_300
        return pv

    def func_1(self):
        return self.rpm_6 * self.rpm_3

    def func_2(self):
        pass


_dict = {
    'rpm_600': 0,
    'rpm_300': 0,
    'rpm_200': 0,
    'rpm_100': 0,
    'rpm_6': 0,
    'rpm_3': 0,
}

for k in _dict:
    _dict[k] = int(input(f'Введите значение {k}: '))

#print(_dict)
rh = Rheology(_dict)

print('Решение 1: ', rh.visc())
print('Решение 2: ', rh.func_1())
```

Comment: Мне кажется, такой способ мне не подойдёт, у меня в  __init__ будет сильно больше 2 значений, и будет больше одной функций в классе Rheology. Но я попробую Ваш вариант, спасибо)

Comment: @Dima раскомментируйте метод `__init__`  если вам надо.

Comment: Я немного дополнил как используются вводимые данные.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rheology:
    Arrts = ('rpm_600', 'rpm_300', 'rpm_200 ',)

    def __init__(self, default=0, arrts=Arrts):
        for a in arrts: setattr(self, a, default)

    def new(self, arrts=Arrts):
        for a in arrts: setattr(self, a, int(input(f'Введите значение {a}: ')))

rh = Rheology()
rh.new()
rh.new(['rpm_300', ])
print(rh.rpm_300)
```